# Indexing a 3d tensor using a 2d tensor

Tags: pytorch

I have a 3d tensor, `source` of shape `(bsz x slen1 x nhd)` and a 2d tensor, `index` of shape `(bsz x slen2)`. More specifically, I have:

```
source = 32 x 20 x 768
index  = 32 x 16
```

Each value in the `index` tensor is in between `[0, 19]` which is the index of the desired vector according to the 2nd dim of the `source` tensor.

After indexing, I am expecting an output tensor of shape, `32 x 16 x 768`.

Currently I am doing this:

```
bsz, _, nhid = source.size()
_, slen = index.size()

source = source.reshape(-1, nhid)
source = source[index.reshape(-1), :]
source = source.reshape(bsz, slen, nhid)
```

So, I am converting the 3d source tensor to a 2d tensor and 2d indexing tensor to a 1d tensor and then perform the indexing. Is this correct?

Is there any better way to do it?

**Update**

I checked that my code is not giving the expected result. To explain what I want, I am providing the following code snippet.

```
source = torch.FloatTensor([
    [[ 0.2413, -0.6667,  0.2621],
     [-0.4216,  0.3722, -1.2258],
     [-0.2436, -1.5746, -0.1270],
     [ 1.6962, -1.3637,  0.8820],
     [ 0.3490, -0.0198,  0.7928]],

    [[-0.0973,  2.3106, -1.8358],
     [-1.9674,  0.5381,  0.2406],
     [ 3.0731,  0.3826, -0.7279],
     [-0.6262,  0.3478, -0.5112],
     [-0.4147, -1.8988, -0.0092]]
     ])

index = torch.LongTensor([[0, 1, 2, 3], 
                          [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

And I want the output tensor as:

```
torch.FloatTensor([
    [[ 0.2413, -0.6667,  0.2621],
     [-0.4216,  0.3722, -1.2258],
     [-0.2436, -1.5746, -0.1270],
     [ 1.6962, -1.3637,  0.8820]],

    [[-1.9674,  0.5381,  0.2406],
     [ 3.0731,  0.3826, -0.7279],
     [-0.6262,  0.3478, -0.5112],
     [-0.4147, -1.8988, -0.0092]]
     ])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**:

```
source[torch.arange(source.shape[0]).unsqueeze(-1), index]
```

Note that `torch.arange(source.shape[0]).unsqueeze(-1)` gives:

```
tensor([[0],
        [1]])  # 2 x 1
```

and `index` is:

```
tensor([[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3, 4]])  # 2 x 4
```

The `arange` indexes the batch dimension while `index` simultaneously indexes the `slen1` dimension. The `unsqueeze` call adds the extra `x 1` dimension to the `arange` result so that the two can be broadcast together.

Comment: Not getting the expected result. Please see my updated post.

Comment: A perfect solution for my case. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem. So, I was actually in need of defining an offset. The following code works for me.

```
index = torch.LongTensor([[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]])
offset = torch.arange(0, source.size(0) * source.size(1), source.size(1))
index = index + offset.unsqueeze(1)

source = source.reshape(-1, source.shape[-1])[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to expand this topic because I have just come into this issue. To subset the third dimension, use the similar codes:

```
dim_1 = torch.arange(source.shape[0]).unsqueeze(-1).unsqueeze(-1)
dim_2 = torch.arange(source.shape[1]).unsqueeze(-1)
dim_3 = torch.arange(2)
subset = source[dim_1, dim_2, dim_3]
```